# Dividing all data based on ID by another data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (tt) of 4 columns where each entry has an ID tag based on which person took a measurement. I'd like to divide the SkinTemp data by the minimum for each ID:

```
dput(head(tt,10))
structure(list(id = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1"), Time = c(139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, 
139), SkinTemp = c(29.559, 29.561, 29.563, 29.564, 29.566, 29.568, 
29.57, 29.572, 29.574, 29.576), HeartRate = c(33.689, 33.689, 
33.689, 33.689, 33.689, 33.689, 33.689, 33.689, 33.689, 33.689
), RespirationRate = c(11.641, 11.641, 11.641, 11.641, 11.641, 
11.641, 11.641, 11.641, 11.641, 11.641)), .Names = c("id", "Time", 
"SkinTemp", "HeartRate", "RespirationRate"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I then found the minimum of each Skin temperature based on ID:

```
TempMins <-aggregate(tt$SkinTemp, by=list(minID=tt$id), FUN=min, na.rm=TRUE)
dput(head(TempMins))
```

Which gives me the following:

```
structure(list(minID = c("1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"
), x = c(29.559, 21.57, 30.311, 34.754, 20.57, 22.879)), .Names = c("minID", 
"x"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I divide all the Skin temperatures (grouped by ID) in the original data by the minimum found for each ID?

I think there is a function for this but I can't seem to get a hit on google.

Comment: `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(SkinTemp/min(SkinTemp))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` without creating a new aggregate dataset.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(tt)`), grouped by 'id', we assign (`:=`) the 'SkinTemp' by dividing the value of 'SkinTemp' by the `min` of 'SkinTemp'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tt)[, SkinTemp := SkinTemp/min(SkinTemp), by = id]
```

---

A `base R` option is `ave`

```
tt$SkinTemp <- with(tt, SkinTemp/ave(SkinTemp, id, FUN = min))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I'd like to go with your answer because of using base R and I can visualise what it's actually doing better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `dplyr` as follows. You can reuse the aggregated data without having to merge two sets, since I use `mutate` instead of `summarise` here:

```
tt %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(SkinTempDivMinTemp = SkinTemp/min(SkinTemp, na.rm=T))
```

Use the `data.table` or `dplyr` method as you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've decided to go with akrun's answer just because I prefer to work in base R as I'm not sure what some of the more complex things mean (e.g. %/%).

Comment: No problem. That is probably the same reason I am not yet using data.table. I can say that switching from R base to `dplyr` for data manipulation has helped me a lot, so far.

Comment: I started using it yesterday so still have to work out all the intricacies but it looks very useful.